# How to get the password in the browser tools from a html div?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, netflix

I have a question. I'm at a friend's house and he forgot his Netflix password, but is still logged into the browser. He has forgotten his password and has no access to the email no access. To change the email but you need logicallyweiße a password. Unfortunately, the password is not in any input but simply in a div where you only see these stars. Is there any way to display the password?

I have searched the DevTools and the source code

Comment: in a div or input field? can you share some screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

If the password is inserted (i.e. by the browser with autofill) into an input element, you can likely change the `type` to `text` rather than `password`.

Otherwise, it's unlikely that the password is saved in the browser at all. If it is part of the Netflix UI itself, you likely won't be able to get the password. Intuitively, Netflix does not know the password and wouldn't be able to send it to the client.

Comment: Ok thank you. Than its impossible, cause its not in an input.